# Debian package verification

Tags: security, debian, packaging, apt-get

I want to distribute a custom .deb package to all debian pc in my company, with periodic updates.

What's the best strategy to make distribution secure (ex. avoiding man in the middle attack that change my package with a dangerous one...) ?

I need to sign the package or is enough to setup a https private repo and install a signed ssl certificate (i can distribute my CA cert to every pc..) ?

Thank,
Igor

Answer (score 1):

A combination of both. You should sign your packages to make sure that what you're sending is what's installed. Then you should have https on your website, so that you can communicate your key properly.

If it's a completely internal deployment, and you say you can distribute the CA, then you can possibly skip the https/website key distribution and add the repository key using the same mechanism you planned to install the CA.